# read csv with dates and times with Rstudio

Tags: r, date, datetime, dplyr

I am new to R, so, please excuse me if my questions is simple.
I am trying to do data wrangling using rstudio. Here is my data that I have it in excel and I want to have it in another cvs file:

```
Start Date      End Date
9/29/2016 7:05  9/29/2016 7:07
9/29/2016 7:14  9/29/2016 7:18
```

Here is the code that I have written

```
setwd("path")

raw <- read.csv("filename", skip = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% as_tibble()

w <- raw %>% mutate(Start.Date =as.POSIXct(Start.Date, format = "%d%m%Y %H:%M"))%>% 
  mutate(End.Date=as.POSIXct(End.Date, format = "%d%m%Y %H:%M")) %>%

write.csv(w, "outputfile.csv")
```

However, what I see in excel are the "NA" values for the columns that you see above.
Any help, please?

Comment: Should you be using `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"` for format? Yours looks nothing like the sample data.

Comment: If this is "in excel" then why aren't you using the formatting available in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If you can export as proper ISO dates, then package [fasttime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=fasttime) is *by far* your best bet in terms of *speed*.  That package does however use only one format.

If you can at least fix your months and dates to use two-digit dates and times, then package [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) can help:

```
R> pt <- anytime(c("09/29/2016 07:05", "09/29/2016 07:07"))  # corrected input
R> pt
[1] "2016-09-29 07:05:00 CDT" "2016-09-29 07:07:00 CDT"
R> format(pt, "%Y%m%d %H%M")
[1] "20160929 0705" "20160929 0707"
R>
```

Lastly, the question has nothing to do with RStudio. It is a plain R question.